New Relic APM Integration with Azure Function (In-Process) Not Sending Data
I am trying to integrate New Relic APM with an Azure Function (in-process model), but I am not seeing any telemetry data in the New Relic APM. I am using serilog to inject logs into the new relic, I am getting all the logs data successfully, but APM service is not working and not getting created.
Environment:
Azure Function Runtime: In-Process
Function App Runtime Version: .NET Core 8, v4
Packages installed
<PackageReference Include="NewRelic.Agent" Version="10.33.1" />
<PackageReference Include="NewRelic.LogEnrichers.Serilog" Version="1.2.0" />


<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="4.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="8.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="8.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Formatting.Compact" Version="3.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="8.0.4" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.NewRelic.Logs" Version="1.3.0" />

Startup.cs file
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();
    
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Is(Enum.Parse<LogEventLevel>("Information", true)) 
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .Enrich.WithNewRelicLogsInContext()
        .WriteTo.NewRelicLogs( 
            endpointUrl: "https://log-api.newrelic.com/log/v1",
            applicationName: "Events.Function(DevOne)",
            licenseKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        .CreateLogger();
    builder.Services.AddLogging(lb =>
    {
        lb.AddSerilog(Log.Logger, true);
    });

    builder.Services.RegisterApplicationServices(context.ApplicationRootPath);
}
}

Settings inserted into the environment variable
"CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING": 1,
"CORECLR_PROFILER": "{36032161-FFC0-4B61-B559-F6C5D41BAE5A}",
"CORECLR_PROFILER_PATH": "",
"CORECLR_NEWRELIC_HOME": "",
"NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY": "",
"NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME": "Events.Function(DevOne)",
"NEW_RELIC_APPLICATION_LOGGING_ENABLED": "false",

I have tried multiple solutions but every time I got only logs but not the application traces in APM service.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks
